# icarousel viewForItemAtIndex is not getting called?

Tags: ios, icarousel

I am using NickLockwood's `iCarousel`. I am not getting why `viewForItemAtIndex` is not getting called.(Setting the breakpoint and its not getting hit.)Everything was properly done.
`datasource` and `delegate` was set to self.
`iCarousel` is alloc in `viewDidLoad`.
 Type is also given.
What's the problem?
Anyone came accross such issue ?

Comment: have you implemented the protocols in your header?

Comment: @Daniel yes Everything is done.

Comment: best way is to refer the examples given along with the library and compare if you are missing anything? maybe u haven't set <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate> in your .h or .m file or if your using storyboards or xib then set it from there

Comment: @suhit Everything is properly done.
`numberOfItemsInCarousel` is getting called but not `viewForItemAtIndex`

Comment: can you put the code in viewForItemAtIndex method

Comment: @suhit What's the use of putting the code if it is not getting called.(i have checked by putting break point there and it is not getting hit.)

Comment: it's very hard to help when no code is given, best way for you to recheck all your code against the existing examples if you are missing anything

Comment: Check numberOfItemsInCarousel return greater than Zero.if numberOfItemsInCarousel return zero means that time viewForItemAtIndex is didn't call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check numberOfItemsInCarousel return greater than Zero.if numberOfItemsInCarousel return zero means that time viewForItemAtIndex is didn't call.

Comment: why array.count is returning (null) have to look after it now.
But Thanks.It works when i return number .